# Is there an even more simple way to query an Entity with Join table

Tags: c#, sql, join, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get Hardware a user owns and the database has a " * to * " joining table, is there a way to make this even more simple? I'm not aware of how to if there is.

```
        UserRecord = _userRepository.GetUserByID(userKey.UserId);
        var hjoiner = _hardwareUserRepository.GetHardwareUsers().Where(s => s.UserId == UserRecord.Id);

        foreach (var h in hjoiner) 
            _hardwareRepository.GetHardwares().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == h.HardwareId);
```

ps yes I am going to refactor things to not have a repository for every table.

Comment: Is this really EF core? Where does GetHardwares() comes from?

Comment: One simplification is to remove the repository layer and work on the EF repositories (i.e. DbSets) directly. For the rest we need to see the class model and mapping code (if present). You seem to describe a many-to-many relationship, but descriptions are always vague.

Answer (score 0):

If your entity looks like this

```
    public class HardwareUser
    {
        public int HardwareId { get; set; }
        public Hardware Hardware { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

you can query as follows

```
var hardwares = _hardwareUserRepository.GetHardwareUsers().Where(s => s.UserId == UserRecord.Id).Select(h=>h.Hardware).ToList();
```